# Can not understand this Map.entry parameter

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

How does this code work?

```
private double Summa(Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Double>>> i,int[] array)
```

Don't really understand how this parameter works. 
Map.entry returns a collection of whats in the map if im not mistaken.
But does this iterate trough all the entries in the map?

Comment: `Map.Entry` doesn't return a collection. It represents a single entry in the map. And yes, with `Iterator<Entry>`, you can iterate over all the entries.

Comment: Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). *«A map entry (key-value pair). The `Map.entrySet` method returns a collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class.»*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Iterator` iterates over the `Set` of `<Map.Entry>` objects. In order to pass an `Iterator` to the method you have to do:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
Summa(iterator, array);
```

where you have to have the `array` variable defined as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. `Map.Entry` does not return anything. `Map.Entry` is a type. Actually it points to class `Entry`, which is nested within class `Map`.

What you actually have there is **an iterator that iterates over entries that map integers to lists of doubles**.